# Python Subprocess Empty Output

Tags: python, process, subprocess

I have this code:

```
pprocess = subprocess.Popen('PROGRAM', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

while True:
    output = pprocess.stdout.readline()
    print 'output = ', output
```

But the output is not being printed using the python code, but instead it is being printed **on the console** and it appears to be printed directly from the process.

Does anyone came across this issue?

Comment: what is `PROGRAM` returning when you call it IN TERMINAL?

Comment: It prints the output correctly on the terminal

Comment: You need to move the `popen` as well into the while loop.

Comment: Why? It will cause the popen to be opened every time

Answer (score 2):

> But the output is not being printed using the python code, but instead it is being printed on the console

It seems the output is being printed on the STDERR stream, rather than the STDOUT stream; you're only capturing the STDOUT.

So, consume the `stderr` stream (too):

```
pprocess = subprocess.Popen('PROGRAM', stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
# Checking just the STDERR here
for line in pprocess.stderr:
    print(line)
```

As a side note, rather that using `readline()` in a `while` loop, just iterate over the file-like object provided by `Popen.stdout`/`Popen.stderr`, which are iterators.

Comment: The " for line in pprocess.stderr: " line appears to be blocking, the flow stops there

Comment: @JayR.W From terminal, run `program 2>/dev/null` . Do you get any output? (This is to confirm that the output actually is being written to STDERR)

Comment: The output that is being written is different from the output I am receiving from this line of code: " print = self.sip_process.stderr.readline() "

Answer (score -1):

Once you read from the `stdout stream` by doing `stdout.readline` it becomes empty. You either have to move your `Popen` call into the while loop or change your logic:

```
while True:
    pprocess = subprocess.Popen('PROGRAM', stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = pprocess.stdout.readline()
    print 'output = ', output
```